# Android studio Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrf.class
```

I want to add google play services to my project so i put this line in build.gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

So I had to enable multidex and I followed android doc, adding this in build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

I add this in android manifest :

```
<application 
...
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

But I have the error I wrote above. I've found a lot of questions relative to this problem (app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex) but not with that (duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrf.class).

I tried some solutions like remove some google libraries but I don't know what refers to internal/zzrf.class.

Here is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.djey.testgoogleplus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Go to your build.gradle and set multiDexEnabled=true it happened cause you exceed the 65,000 methods java set. And it normally occurs when you add some modules to your app

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's already done, I said it in the question

Comment: Which library did you add when it all started? Or paste your build.gradle file

Comment: I put my build.gradle file

Comment: Do this and let's see the outcome `minifyEnable=true` and  `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: I have the same error putting minifyenabled true

Comment: Do you use any third party library?

Comment: No I just use google play services and multidex

Comment: @Jey10 I added answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced same problem. In my case I used home made Android library used by My Android app. Which means 1 project with 2 separate modules, while the app module depends on the library module. 
Both have support of multidex. The root cause was inconsistency between google play services version. In the app module I used 7.8.+ and in the library I used 8.1.+. So I just updated both to same 8.1.+ and that fixed for me. So my answer is to check all the libs you depend on and may 1 of them using google play services version below yours.

Comment: Finally, I created another project and just doing the same thing : putting google play services and multidex, the problem didn't appear anymore. I think your answer can work for some cases, in other cases just create another project.

Comment: Just run ./gradlew dependencies to find out which modules include conflicting versions of the Play services.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files under build folder of that project. In my case, it is the jar file of the whole google play conflict with the jar file of only ads service.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment :  I created another project and just did the same things : putting google play services and multidex, the problem didn't appear anymore.